# Am trying to pause a video on viewpager swipe

Tags: android, responsive-design, android-viewpager

I've searched and this is the possible answer I got and I don't know how to go about it, I don't just understand

````
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
       // find your player and pause it if it's not in the current view
       // Ideally you notify a viewModel that is shared between your paged
       // fragments here and let each one determine if it needs to pause 
       // its player.
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) { // do nothing }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float offset, int offsetInPixels) { // do nothing }
})```.

Or is there a better explanation on how to pause or stop video in viewpager when scrolled to the next one
````